# Sequence of API Calls in Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee

I have a sequence of 3 API calls that need to execute to update different fields in a database. It is a single transaction.

The problem is if one of the API call fails I need to rollback my transaction.

The sequence of API Calls are

1. editRequest
2. AddWorklog
3. Addnote

Could anyone explain how if one API call fails the other API calls can be rolled back as well?

Comment: When your system is set up correctly, then all you need to to is to roll back the "single transaction". With set up correctly I mean that the transaction is either an XA Transaction when there are multiple resources involved or a normal sql transaction that spans across all 3 calls.

Comment: The question is how you are creating the transaction. Do you do it explicitly? Are you using something like spring and an AOP based transaction demarcation? Also: What do you mean that one of the calls fails? Does it throw an exception or does it simply not update what it should update?

Comment: Please post the code you've written, it's usually not possible to answer a question without seeing your code.

Comment: as @SuperBiasedMan said, its almost impossible to help you right now. But here is a pseudo code:-

start transaction;
try {
 call api 1
 call api 2
 call api 3
} catch (Exception e){
roll back transaction;
}
end transaction;